# Broken pipe error when trying to send anything over pipe between processes with sending process running Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, pipe, python-multiprocessing

I am playing around with `Pipe` and `Process` from the `multiprocessing` module (Python 3.8). My initial program looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


class Process1(object):
    def __init__(self, pipe_out):
        self.pipe_out = pipe_out

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                print("Sending message to process 2")
                self.pipe_out.send(["hello"])
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass


class Process2(object):
    def __init__(self, pipe_in):
        self.pipe_in = pipe_in

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.pipe_in.poll():
                request = self.pipe_in.recv()
                method = request[0]
                args = request[1:]

                try:
                    getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
                except AttributeError as ae:
                    print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

            print("Process 2 done with receiving")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def hello_callback(self):
        print("Process 1 said hello")


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pipe_proc1_out, pipe_proc2_in = Pipe()

        self.proc1 = Process(
            target=Process1,
            args=(pipe_proc1_out, )
        )

        self.proc2 = Process(
            target=Process2,
            args=(pipe_proc2_in, )
        )

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.proc1.start()
            self.proc2.start()

            while True:
                continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Quitting processes...")
            self.proc1.join(1)
            if self.proc1.is_alive():
                self.proc1.terminate()

            self.proc2.join(1)
            if self.proc2.is_alive():
                self.proc2.terminate()

            print("Finished")


def pipes():
    c = Controller()
    c.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipes()
```

I have a `Controller` instance that runs until a keyboard interruption is received. It also handles two processes `Process1` and `Process2` with the former constantly sending and the latter constantly receiving.

The code above is a skeleton for a larger undertaking that involves a complex GUI (PySide), image processing (OpenCV) and a game engine (Panda3D). So I tried to add Tkinter as a GUI example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import tkinter as tk


class Process1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, pipe_out):
        self.pipe_out = pipe_out

        self.setup_gui()
        self.run()

    def setup_gui(self):
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        lb1 = tk.Label(self.app, text="Message:")
        lb1.pack()
        self.ent1 = tk.Entry(self.app)
        self.ent1.pack()
        btn1 = tk.Button(self.app, text="Say hello to other process",
                         command=self.btn1_clicked)
        btn1.pack()

    def btn1_clicked(self):
        msg = self.ent1.get()
        self.pipe_out.send(["hello", msg])

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.app.mainloop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass


class Process2(object):
    def __init__(self, pipe_in):
        self.pipe_in = pipe_in

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.pipe_in.poll():
                request = self.pipe_in.recv()
                method = request[0]
                args = request[1:]

                try:
                    getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
                except AttributeError as ae:
                    print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

            print("Process 2 done with receiving")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def hello_callback(self, msg):
        print("Process 1 say\"" + msg + "\"")


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pipe_proc1_out, pipe_proc2_in = Pipe()

        self.proc1 = Process(
            target=Process1,
            args=(pipe_proc1_out, )
        )

        self.proc2 = Process(
            target=Process2,
            args=(pipe_proc2_in, )
        )

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.proc1.start()
            self.proc2.start()

            while True:
                continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Quitting processes...")
            self.proc1.join(1)
            if self.proc1.is_alive():
                self.proc1.terminate()

            self.proc2.join(1)
            if self.proc2.is_alive():
                self.proc2.terminate()

            print("Finished")


def pipes():
    c = Controller()
    c.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipes()
```

Notice that currently the Tkinter window can only be closed if the "parent" process is interrupted via keyboard.

Whenever I click the button and invoke the button's command, my program goes into an error state with the following message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\THS\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\PythonPlayground\pipes_advanced.py", line 26, in btn1_clicked
    self.pipe_out.send(["hello", 1, 2])
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\THS\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\THS\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
```

At first I thought that the problem is with the value I'm receiving from the `Entry.get()` call (my Tkinter skills are rusty). I printed `msg` and got the text from the widget.

Next thing I tried was to put a constant string as the value of the argument that I sent over the pipe:

```
def btn1_clicked(self):
    self.pipe_out.send(["hello", "world"])
```

The same error appeared. Catching the exception `BrokenPipeError` doesn't really do me any good (except if I want to handle the case when the pipe is broken I guess).

If I do the same for the first version of the program (without Tkinter), it works. This leads me to believe that my problem comes from the way I have integrated Tkinter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is that you poll the pipe, but the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.poll) says:

> poll([timeout])
>
> Return whether there is any data available to be read.
> If timeout is not specified then it will return immediately.

In the first example it works because when starting `Process1` you send data to the pipe immediately:

```py
    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                print("Sending message to process 2")
                self.pipe_out.send(["hello"])
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

And you do this continuously so the `.poll` will return `True` and the loop in `Process2` will continue.

As with `tkinter` nothing gets sent to the pipe immediately it waits for user to click a button, by the time any of that can happen the `Process2` already has called `poll` and it immediately returned `False` and it didn't even start that loop. If you notice then it also almost immediately prints in the terminal that

> "Process 2 done with receiving"

To solve this issue the easiest seems to use

```py
while self.pipe_in.poll(None):
```

which per the docs means

> "If timeout is None then an infinite timeout is used."

and for something like user interface this seems to be the best fit (from user's perspective at least (or so I think)) so basically your `run` method in `Process2` should look like this:

```py
    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.pipe_in.poll(None):
                request = self.pipe_in.recv()
                method = request[0]
                args = request[1:]

                try:
                    getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
                except AttributeError as ae:
                    print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

            print("Process 2 done with receiving")
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
            pass
```

Also not related to the problem but there seems to be no need to inherit from `tk.Frame` in `Process1` (or `object` in `Process2` (unless you really need to make it compatible with Python2)), you almost could inherit from `tk.Tk`, that should make it easier to actually use it as the main window since `self` would be the `Tk` instance

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for point all the issues out. I noticed in another program of mine where I run Panda3D is use a task that is triggered via the task manager of the engine for the polling. So that is why the issue never occurred there.

As for the `Frame` inheritance - indeed. I had it initially as `object` but then copied another example from the internet and I guess it was old and had it in there. :D Anyway the Tkinter dependency will be gone and replaced with PySide. Still, well spotted.

Comment: @rbaleksandar thanks, also there is another issue which has to be handled (edited with a possible solution but I guess it should be handled so that it closes the process too or sth) which is an `EOFError`, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.recv): _recv() Raises EOFError if there is nothing left to receive and the other end was closed._

Comment: LOL I just got the error and looked back here. Thanks for the extra step. It definitely provides a much cleaner exit. I will also add `close()` for the pipes and last but not least make the close event of the Tkinter window able to close the underlying `Controller` and all other processes.