# Specifying which item is to be consumed by which consumer for a Python multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, pipe, python-multiprocessing

The following code is work in progress. It is an upgrade from the one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69912856/1559401) regarding another issue. It uses a pipe for communicating (currently only the close event) data between the GUI (producer) and the controller (consumer) that controls the termination of the application (just like in the previous version of the code). The essential upgrade is the replacement of the pipe (for communicating data between the GUI and the image processing process) with a queue.

The reason I have picked a queue is because it is thread-safe and in the future I would like to move each independent image processing task to a separate thread (if avaialble). For example after generating a grayscale image from the original one there are multiple independent steps that I can undertakes using it - Gaussian and the Harris corner detection (1), Canny edge detection (2, currently an issue with displaying the resulting image using `ImageTk` so ignore) etc. The GUI is there to just visualize so the order it receives the separate items is not important (hence the queue).

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Queue
from threading import Thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor # For future use
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import atexit
import cv2
import os


class ProcessGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, queue_gui_ip, pipe_gui_co_out):
        print("[ProcessGUI]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        self.queue_gui_ip = queue_gui_ip
        self.pipe_gui_co_out = pipe_gui_co_out

        self.poll_image_data_thread = Thread(target=self.poll_image_data)

        self.setup_gui()
        self.run()

    def setup_gui(self):
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        self.app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_event)

        fr_browse_controls = ttk.Frame(self.app)
        fr_browse_controls.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")

        lb_browse = ttk.Label(fr_browse_controls, text="Path to image file:")
        lb_browse.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.ent_browse = ttk.Entry(fr_browse_controls)
        self.ent_browse.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill="x")

        btn_browse = ttk.Button(fr_browse_controls, text="Browse", command=self.btn_browse_clicked)
        btn_browse.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        self.edge_algs = tk.StringVar(self.app)
        om_edge_algs = ttk.OptionMenu(self.app, self.edge_algs, "canny", "canny", "sobelx", "sobely", "sobelxy")
        om_edge_algs.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")

        self.pb_load = ttk.Progressbar(self.app, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode="determinate")
        self.pb_load.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")

        tw_images = ttk.Notebook(self.app)
        tw_images.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_original = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_original = None
        tw_images.add(tb_original, text="RGB")
        self.lb_image_original = ttk.Label(tb_original, image=None)
        self.lb_image_original.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_gray = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_gray = None
        tw_images.add(tb_gray, text="Grayscale")
        self.lb_image_gray = ttk.Label(tb_gray, image=None)
        self.lb_image_gray.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_gaussian = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_gaussian = None
        tw_images.add(tb_gaussian, text="Gaussian")
        self.lb_image_gaussian = ttk.Label(tb_gaussian, image=None)
        self.lb_image_gaussian.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_edges = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_edges = None
        tw_images.add(tb_edges, text="Edges")
        self.lb_image_edges = ttk.Label(tb_edges, image=None)
        self.lb_image_edges.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_corners = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_corners = None
        tw_images.add(tb_corners, text="Harris corners")
        self.lb_image_corners = ttk.Label(tb_corners, image=None)
        self.lb_image_corners.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.poll_image_data_thread.start()
            self.app.mainloop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close_event()

    def poll_image_data(self):
        while True:
            request = self.queue_gui_ip.get()
            method = request[0]
            args = request[1:]

            print("------------[ProcessGUI]------------")
            print("Method: " + method)
            print("------------------------------------")

            try:
                getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
            except AttributeError as ae:
                print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

    def display_image_dims_callback(self, height, width, channels):
        print("[ProcessGUI]")
        print("Height: " + str(height))
        print("Width: " + str(width))
        print("Channels: " + str(channels))

    def display_image_processing_progress_callback(self, progress):
        progress = 0 + ((100 - 0) / (len(ProcessImageProcessing.ProcessingSteps) - 0)) * (progress - 0)
        print("[ProcessGUI]: Updating progress to " + str(progress) + "%")
        self.pb_load["value"] = progress

    def display_image_original_gray_callback(self, image_original, image_gray):
        self.image_original = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_original))
        self.lb_image_original.configure(image=self.image_original)

        self.image_gray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_gray))
        self.lb_image_gray.configure(image=self.image_gray)

    def display_image_gaussian_callback(self, image_gaussian):
        self.image_gaussian = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_gaussian))
        self.lb_image_gaussian.configure(image=self.image_gaussian)

    def display_image_edges_callback(self, image_edges):
        self.image_edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_edges))
        self.lb_image_edges.configure(image=self.image_edges)

    def display_image_corners_callback(self, image_corners):
        self.image_corners = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_corners))
        self.lb_image_corners.configure(image=self.image_corners)

    def btn_browse_clicked(self):
        filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".",
                                                 title="Select image",
                                                 filetypes=(
                                                     ("Portable Network graphics", "*.png"),
                                                     ("All files", "*.*")))
        self.ent_browse.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.ent_browse.insert(0, filename)

        edge_alg = self.edge_algs.get()
        self.queue_gui_ip.put(["process_image", filename, edge_alg])

    def close_event(self):
        print("[ProcessGUI]: Shutting down")
        self.pipe_gui_co_out.send(["close"])
        if self.poll_image_data_thread.is_alive():
            self.poll_image_data_thread.join()

        self.pipe_gui_co_out.close()

        self.app.destroy()


class ProcessImageProcessing(object):
    ProcessingSteps = [
        "rgb",
        "gray",
        "gaussian",
        "edges",
        "corners"
    ]

    def __init__(self, queue_gui_ip):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        self.queue_gui_ip = queue_gui_ip

        # atexit.register(self.close)
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            request = self.queue_gui_ip.get()
            method = request[0]
            args = request[1:]

            print("------[ProcessImageProcessing]------")
            print("Method: " + method)
            print("------------------------------------")

            if "display_" in method:
                # Skip incoming requests that contain methods meant for ProcessGUI class
                continue

            try:
                getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
            except AttributeError as ae:
                print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

    def process_image_callback(self, image_path, edge_alg):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: Received file \"" + image_path + "\"")
        try:
            progress = 0
            original_bgr = cv2.imread(image_path)
            original_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(original_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            (height, width, channels) = original_bgr.shape[:3]
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_dims", height, width, channels])
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(original_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_original_gray", original_rgb, gray])
            gaussian = self.process_image_gaussian(gray)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_gaussian", gaussian])
            try:
                edges = self.process_image_edges(gaussian, edge_alg)
                if not edges:
                    print("Unknown edge detection algorithm")
                else:
                    progress += 1
                    self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
                    self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_edges", edges])
            except:
                pass
            corners = self.process_image_corners(original_rgb, gray)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_corners", corners])
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Exception: " + str(ex))

    def process_image_gaussian(self, image_gray):
        gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_gray, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        return gaussian

    def process_image_edges(self, image_gaussian, edge_alg):
        edges = None

        if edge_alg not in ["canny", "sobelx", "sobely", "sobelxy"]:
            return edges

        # Sobel edge detection
        # Sobel edge detection on the X axis
        if edge_alg == "sobelx":
            print("Sobel X")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=5)
        # Sobel edge detection on the Y axis
        elif edge_alg == "sobely":
            print("Sobel Y")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=5)
        # Combined X and Y Sobel edge detection
        elif edge_alg == "sobelxy":
            print("Sobel XY")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=1, ksize=5)
        # Canny edge detection
        elif edge_alg == "canny":
            print("Canny")
            edges = cv2.Canny(image=image_gaussian, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)

        return edges

    def process_image_corners(self, image_original, image_gray):
        original_with_corners = image_original
        corners = cv2.cornerHarris(image_gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

        # result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
        corners = cv2.dilate(corners, None)

        # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
        original_with_corners[corners > 0.01 * corners.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

        return original_with_corners

    def close(self):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: Shutting down")


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("[Controller]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        queue_gui_ip = Queue()
        pipe_gui_co_out, self.pipe_co_in = Pipe()

        self.gui = Process(
            target=ProcessGUI,
            args=(queue_gui_ip, pipe_gui_co_out)
        )

        self.ip = Process(
            target=ProcessImageProcessing,
            args=(queue_gui_ip,)
        )

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.gui.start()
            self.ip.start()

            while self.pipe_co_in.poll(None):
                try:
                    request = self.pipe_co_in.recv()
                    method = request[0]
                    args = request[1:]

                    try:
                        getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
                    except AttributeError as ae:
                        print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))
                except EOFError:
                    # Raised when nothing to receive from pipe
                    pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close_callback()
        except BrokenPipeError:
            self.close_callback()

    def close_callback(self):
        print("Quitting processes...")
        self.gui.join(1)
        if self.gui.is_alive():
            self.gui.terminate()

        self.ip.join(1)
        if self.ip.is_alive():
            self.ip.terminate()

        print("Finished")


def main():
    c = Controller()
    c.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My problem is in the way a `Queue` works. Unlike a duplex `Pipe`, where I have never encountered this issue, a Queue offers its items to both processes - `ProcessGUI` and `ProcessImageProcessing`. After an item is retrieved it is (naturally) consumed. The problem is that my main producer - the `ProcessImageProcessing` - received a large amount of the items it has put into the queue for the lesser producer - the `ProcessGUI`. This leads to items being consumed by the wrong consumer.

I am looking for a way to solve this problem. At first I thought that I can consume an item and, if it is not meant for the consumer that consumed it, put it back into the queue (hence the print statements and the

```
if "display_" in method:
    continue
```

inside `ProcessImageProcessing`, where I was thinking of bouncing back the item that is meant for `ProcessGUI`. This clearly has many flaws including checking every item for validity and more importantly the absence of a guarantee that an item, that was put back into the queue, will next time be consumed by the correct consumer. This can potentially lead to a scenario, where the item is continuously consumed by the wrong consumer and bounced back indefinitely.

My next thought is to perhaps add a `Pipe` for incoming data (`ProcessGUI` to `ProcessImageProcessing`) and have the `Queue` be used for transferring the image data from a single producer (`ProcessImageProcessing`) and a single consumer (`ProcessGUI`). This seems like the right way to go but I am curious if there is another way so that I learn more about IPC and `Pipe`/`Queue` in Python.

---

Here is the updated code (far from perfect :D) with the additional `Pipe` and a "single producer, single consumer" `Queue`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Queue
from threading import Thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import atexit
import cv2
import os


class ProcessGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, queue_ip_gui, pipe_gui_ip_in, pipe_gui_co_out):
        print("[ProcessGUI]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        self.queue_ip_gui = queue_ip_gui
        self.pipe_gui_ip_in = pipe_gui_ip_in
        self.pipe_gui_co_out = pipe_gui_co_out

        self.poll_image_data_thread = Thread(target=self.poll_image_data)

        self.setup_gui()
        self.run()

    def setup_gui(self):
        # SAME AS ABOVE
        # ...

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.poll_image_data_thread.start()
            self.app.mainloop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close_event()

    def poll_image_data(self):
        while True:
            request = self.queue_ip_gui.get()
            method = request[0]
            args = request[1:]

            try:
                getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
            except AttributeError as ae:
                print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

    def display_image_dims_callback(self, height, width, channels):
        print("[ProcessGUI]")
        print("Height: " + str(height))
        print("Width: " + str(width))
        print("Channels: " + str(channels))

    def display_image_processing_progress_callback(self, progress):
        progress = 0 + ((100 - 0) / (len(ProcessImageProcessing.ProcessingSteps) - 0)) * (progress - 0)
        print("[ProcessGUI]: Updating progress to " + str(progress) + "%")
        self.pb_load["value"] = progress

    def display_image_original_gray_callback(self, image_original, image_gray):
        self.image_original = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_original))
        self.lb_image_original.configure(image=self.image_original)

        self.image_gray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_gray))
        self.lb_image_gray.configure(image=self.image_gray)

    def display_image_gaussian_callback(self, image_gaussian):
        self.image_gaussian = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_gaussian))
        self.lb_image_gaussian.configure(image=self.image_gaussian)

    def display_image_edges_callback(self, image_edges):
        self.image_edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_edges))
        self.lb_image_edges.configure(image=self.image_edges)

    def display_image_corners_callback(self, image_corners):
        self.image_corners = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_corners))
        self.lb_image_corners.configure(image=self.image_corners)

    def btn_browse_clicked(self):
        filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".",
                                                 title="Select image",
                                                 filetypes=(
                                                     ("Portable Network graphics", "*.png"),
                                                     ("All files", "*.*")))
        self.ent_browse.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.ent_browse.insert(0, filename)

        edge_alg = self.edge_algs.get()
        self.pipe_gui_ip_in.send(["process_image", filename, edge_alg])

    def close_event(self):
        print("[ProcessGUI]: Shutting down")
        self.pipe_gui_co_out.send(["close"])
        if self.poll_image_data_thread.is_alive():
            self.poll_image_data_thread.join()

        self.pipe_gui_co_out.close()

        self.app.destroy()


class ProcessImageProcessing(object):
    ProcessingSteps = [
        "rgb",
        "gray",
        "gaussian",
        "edges",
        "corners"
    ]

    def __init__(self, queue_gui_ip, pipe_gui_ip_out):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        self.queue_gui_ip = queue_gui_ip
        self.pipe_gui_ip_out = pipe_gui_ip_out
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.pipe_gui_ip_out.poll(None):
                try:
                    request = self.pipe_gui_ip_out.recv()
                    method = request[0]
                    args = request[1:]
    
                    try:
                        getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
                    except AttributeError as ae:
                        print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))
    
                except EOFError:
                    # Raised when nothing to receive from pipe
                    pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close()
        except BrokenPipeError:
            # Raised when exiting the process
            self.close()

    def process_image_callback(self, image_path, edge_alg):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: Received file \"" + image_path + "\"")
        try:
            progress = 0
            original_bgr = cv2.imread(image_path)
            original_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(original_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            (height, width, channels) = original_bgr.shape[:3]
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_dims", height, width, channels])
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(original_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_original_gray", original_rgb, gray])
            gaussian = self.process_image_gaussian(gray)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_gaussian", gaussian])
            try:
                edges = self.process_image_edges(gaussian, edge_alg)
                if not edges:
                    print("Unknown edge detection algorithm")
                else:
                    progress += 1
                    self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
                    self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_edges", edges])
            except:
                pass
            corners = self.process_image_corners(original_rgb, gray)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_ip.put(["display_image_corners", corners])
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Exception: " + str(ex))

    def process_image_gaussian(self, image_gray):
        gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_gray, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        return gaussian

    def process_image_edges(self, image_gaussian, edge_alg):
        edges = None

        if edge_alg not in ["canny", "sobelx", "sobely", "sobelxy"]:
            return edges

        if edge_alg == "sobelx":
            print("Sobel X")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=5)
        elif edge_alg == "sobely":
            print("Sobel Y")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=5)
        elif edge_alg == "sobelxy":
            print("Sobel XY")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=1, ksize=5)
        elif edge_alg == "canny":
            print("Canny")
            edges = cv2.Canny(image=image_gaussian, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)

        return edges

    def process_image_corners(self, image_original, image_gray):
        original_with_corners = image_original
        corners = cv2.cornerHarris(image_gray, 2, 3, 0.04)
        corners = cv2.dilate(corners, None)
        original_with_corners[corners > 0.01 * corners.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

        return original_with_corners

    def close(self):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: Shutting down")


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("[Controller]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        queue_ip_gui = Queue()
        pipe_gui_ip_in, pipe_gui_ip_out = Pipe()
        pipe_gui_co_out, self.pipe_co_in = Pipe()

        self.gui = Process(
            target=ProcessGUI,
            args=(queue_ip_gui, pipe_gui_ip_in, pipe_gui_co_out)
        )

        self.ip = Process(
            target=ProcessImageProcessing,
            args=(queue_ip_gui, pipe_gui_ip_out)
        )

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.gui.start()
            self.ip.start()

            while self.pipe_co_in.poll(None):
                try:
                    request = self.pipe_co_in.recv()
                    method = request[0]
                    args = request[1:]

                    try:
                        getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
                    except AttributeError as ae:
                        print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))
                except EOFError:
                    # Raised when nothing to receive from pipe
                    pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close_callback()
        except BrokenPipeError:
            self.close_callback()

    def close_callback(self):
        print("Quitting processes...")
        self.gui.join(1)
        if self.gui.is_alive():
            self.gui.terminate()

        self.ip.join(1)
        if self.ip.is_alive():
            self.ip.terminate()

        print("Finished")


def pipes():
    c = Controller()
    c.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipes()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to go is to have an input queue for the `ProcessImageProcessing` process and a output queue that this process will write its results to and from which `ProcessGUI` will read from.

I would also make `ProcessGui` a thread launched from the main process and get rid of using a `Pipe` to communicate the close event and use instead an actual `threading.Event` instance. This allows the main thread to simply wait for the GUI to close without burning CPU cycles in a polling loop. Finally, by using *daemon* thread for doing the  queue `get` requests in `ProcessGui` and making the `ProcessImageProcessing` process a *daemon* process, the logic becomes somewhat simplified.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Queue
from threading import Thread, Event
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import os

class ProcessGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, queue_gui_ip, queue_gui_op, termination_event):
        print("[ProcessGUI]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        self.queue_gui_ip = queue_gui_ip
        self.queue_gui_op = queue_gui_op
        self.termination_event = termination_event

        self.poll_image_data_thread = Thread(target=self.poll_image_data, daemon=True)

        self.setup_gui()
        self.run()

    def setup_gui(self):
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        self.app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_event)

        fr_browse_controls = ttk.Frame(self.app)
        fr_browse_controls.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")

        lb_browse = ttk.Label(fr_browse_controls, text="Path to image file:")
        lb_browse.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.ent_browse = ttk.Entry(fr_browse_controls)
        self.ent_browse.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill="x")

        btn_browse = ttk.Button(fr_browse_controls, text="Browse", command=self.btn_browse_clicked)
        btn_browse.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        self.edge_algs = tk.StringVar(self.app)
        om_edge_algs = ttk.OptionMenu(self.app, self.edge_algs, "canny", "canny", "sobelx", "sobely", "sobelxy")
        om_edge_algs.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")

        self.pb_load = ttk.Progressbar(self.app, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode="determinate")
        self.pb_load.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")

        tw_images = ttk.Notebook(self.app)
        tw_images.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_original = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_original = None
        tw_images.add(tb_original, text="RGB")
        self.lb_image_original = ttk.Label(tb_original, image=None)
        self.lb_image_original.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_gray = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_gray = None
        tw_images.add(tb_gray, text="Grayscale")
        self.lb_image_gray = ttk.Label(tb_gray, image=None)
        self.lb_image_gray.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_gaussian = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_gaussian = None
        tw_images.add(tb_gaussian, text="Gaussian")
        self.lb_image_gaussian = ttk.Label(tb_gaussian, image=None)
        self.lb_image_gaussian.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_edges = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_edges = None
        tw_images.add(tb_edges, text="Edges")
        self.lb_image_edges = ttk.Label(tb_edges, image=None)
        self.lb_image_edges.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tb_corners = ttk.Frame(tw_images)
        self.image_corners = None
        tw_images.add(tb_corners, text="Harris corners")
        self.lb_image_corners = ttk.Label(tb_corners, image=None)
        self.lb_image_corners.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.poll_image_data_thread.start()
            self.app.mainloop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close_event()

    def poll_image_data(self):
        while True:
            request = self.queue_gui_op.get()
            method = request[0]
            args = request[1:]

            print("------------[ProcessGUI]------------")
            print("Method: " + method)
            print("------------------------------------")

            try:
                getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
            except AttributeError as ae:
                print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

    def display_image_dims_callback(self, height, width, channels):
        print("[ProcessGUI]")
        print("Height: " + str(height))
        print("Width: " + str(width))
        print("Channels: " + str(channels))

    def display_image_processing_progress_callback(self, progress):
        progress = 0 + ((100 - 0) / (len(ProcessImageProcessing.ProcessingSteps) - 0)) * (progress - 0)
        print("[ProcessGUI]: Updating progress to " + str(progress) + "%")
        self.pb_load["value"] = progress

    def display_image_original_gray_callback(self, image_original, image_gray):
        self.image_original = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_original))
        self.lb_image_original.configure(image=self.image_original)

        self.image_gray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_gray))
        self.lb_image_gray.configure(image=self.image_gray)

    def display_image_gaussian_callback(self, image_gaussian):
        self.image_gaussian = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_gaussian))
        self.lb_image_gaussian.configure(image=self.image_gaussian)

    def display_image_edges_callback(self, image_edges):
        self.image_edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_edges))
        self.lb_image_edges.configure(image=self.image_edges)

    def display_image_corners_callback(self, image_corners):
        self.image_corners = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image_corners))
        self.lb_image_corners.configure(image=self.image_corners)

    def btn_browse_clicked(self):
        filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".",
                                                 title="Select image",
                                                 filetypes=(
                                                     ("Portable Network graphics", "*.png"),
                                                     ("All files", "*.*")))
        self.ent_browse.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.ent_browse.insert(0, filename)

        edge_alg = self.edge_algs.get()
        self.queue_gui_ip.put(["process_image", filename, edge_alg])

    def close_event(self):
        print("[ProcessGUI]: Shutting down")

        self.app.destroy()
        self.termination_event.set() # show were are terminating


class ProcessImageProcessing(object):
    ProcessingSteps = [
        "rgb",
        "gray",
        "gaussian",
        "edges",
        "corners"
    ]

    def __init__(self, queue_gui_ip, queue_gui_op):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        self.queue_gui_ip = queue_gui_ip
        self.queue_gui_op = queue_gui_op

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            request = self.queue_gui_ip.get()
            method = request[0]
            args = request[1:]

            print("------[ProcessImageProcessing]------")
            print("Method: " + method)
            print("------------------------------------")

            if "display_" in method:
                # Skip incoming requests that contain methods meant for ProcessGUI class
                continue

            try:
                getattr(self, method + "_callback")(*args)
            except AttributeError as ae:
                print("Unknown callback received from pipe", str(ae))

    def process_image_callback(self, image_path, edge_alg):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: Received file \"" + image_path + "\"")
        try:
            progress = 0
            original_bgr = cv2.imread(image_path)
            original_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(original_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            (height, width, channels) = original_bgr.shape[:3]
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_dims", height, width, channels])
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(original_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_original_gray", original_rgb, gray])
            gaussian = self.process_image_gaussian(gray)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_gaussian", gaussian])
            try:
                edges = self.process_image_edges(gaussian, edge_alg)
                if not edges:
                    print("Unknown edge detection algorithm")
                else:
                    progress += 1
                    self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
                    self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_edges", edges])
            except:
                pass
            corners = self.process_image_corners(original_rgb, gray)
            progress += 1
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_processing_progress", progress])
            self.queue_gui_op.put(["display_image_corners", corners])
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Exception: " + str(ex))

    def process_image_gaussian(self, image_gray):
        gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_gray, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        return gaussian

    def process_image_edges(self, image_gaussian, edge_alg):
        edges = None

        if edge_alg not in ["canny", "sobelx", "sobely", "sobelxy"]:
            return edges

        # Sobel edge detection
        # Sobel edge detection on the X axis
        if edge_alg == "sobelx":
            print("Sobel X")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=5)
        # Sobel edge detection on the Y axis
        elif edge_alg == "sobely":
            print("Sobel Y")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=5)
        # Combined X and Y Sobel edge detection
        elif edge_alg == "sobelxy":
            print("Sobel XY")
            edges = cv2.Sobel(src=image_gaussian, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=1, ksize=5)
        # Canny edge detection
        elif edge_alg == "canny":
            print("Canny")
            edges = cv2.Canny(image=image_gaussian, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)

        return edges

    def process_image_corners(self, image_original, image_gray):
        original_with_corners = image_original
        corners = cv2.cornerHarris(image_gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

        # result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
        corners = cv2.dilate(corners, None)

        # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
        original_with_corners[corners > 0.01 * corners.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

        return original_with_corners

    def close(self):
        print("[ProcessImageProcessing]: Shutting down")


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("[Controller]: PID = " + str(os.getpid()))
        queue_gui_ip = Queue()
        queue_gui_op = Queue()

        # A Thread!
        self.termination_event = Event()
        self.gui = Thread(
            target=ProcessGUI,
            args=(queue_gui_ip, queue_gui_op, self.termination_event)
        )

        # Make it a daemon process:
        self.ip = Process(
            target=ProcessImageProcessing,
            args=(queue_gui_ip, queue_gui_op),
            daemon=True
        )

    def run(self):

        try:
            self.gui.start()
            self.ip.start()
            self.termination_event.wait() # wait for termination
            self.close_callback()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close_callback()

    def close_callback(self):
        print("Quitting processes...")
        self.gui.join(1)
        if self.gui.is_alive():
            self.gui.terminate()

        print("Finished")


def main():
    c = Controller()
    c.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does this not resolve your issue or did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry for the later reply. While you offer improvements (which btw I've included in a different version of my initial code), I am still interested in an alternative, where multiple processes share the same queue and each "know" if an item is to be processed by that process or left alone for another. I'm thinking this would require some kind of a broker, which received all the items and then reposts those to queues that are only between it and the process that is the actual target.